# Dynamic JSON Reference Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON file "jFile" in the following format:

```
{
  "Entry1": null,
  "Entry2": "SomeValue"
}
```

And some node.js in the following format correctly updates the files:

```
jFile.Entry1= "SomeText";
fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");
```

However, if I do:

```
var testEnt = 'Entry' + 1;
jFile.testEnt = "SomeText";
fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");
```

The script runs without error, but never updates 'Entry1'. I have tried referencing it in a few ways (jFile.[testEnt] for example), and I get various new and interesting ways it doesn't work.

My questions are:

1. Why? I understand that the script is not understanding that the
   'testEnt' is not correctly understanding that I now mean this as a
   reference, and not a string, but I don't understand what I can do
   about it.
2. How do I dynamically reference entries this way? I'd like
   to make the script flexible, but can't seem to find information on
   how to do this in particular.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you wrote:

```
jFile.[testEnt]
```

The correct syntax is:

```
jFile[testEnt]
```

You are correct in the way you are trying to dynamically access and edit object properties, but you have that minor syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

To update an object with a key inside a var you can do this:

```
obj[varKey] = 'what you want';
```

For your need:

```
var testEnt = 'Entry' + 1;
jFile[testEnt] = "SomeText";
fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jFile = require('./jFile.json');

jFile.Entry1= "SomeText";

fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");

const testEnt = 'Entry' + 6;
jFile[testEnt] = "SomeText";
fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");
```

The mainpoint is here: `jFile[testEnt] = "SomeText";`

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "Entry1": "SomeText",
  "Entry2": "SomeValue",
  "Entry6": "SomeText"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it might help you.

```
var testEnt = 'Entry' + 1;
jFile[testEnt] = "SomeText";
fs.writeFileSync( "jFile.json", JSON.stringify(jFile, null, 2), "utf8");
```